# Supported Serialization Types

Tags: wcf, service, types, wcf-data-services

What types of serialization do WCF data services support?  Is binary serialization an option?  Can someone point me to some documentation from Microsoft on this subject?

Answer (score -1):

Binary serialization is an option, as well as SOAP and REST.

Please see this as a starter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx

Comment: So binary serialization can be used in conjunction with EF 2.0?

Comment: Not possible with WCF data services: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/62771282-936f-45d3-bd7a-12c8947213fe